# помощь по js помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, классы

Всем привет,помогите пожалуйста,есть вот такой массив данных

```
var obj = [{
    name: 'Test',
    expirence: '364 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: false,
    company: 'Company'
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 2',
    expirence: '367 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: false,
    company: 'Company'
  },
  {
    name: 'Test 3',
    expirence: '731 days',
    Frontender: true,
    Backender: false,
    company: 'Company'
  }
];
```

И есть такое задание:
6) добавить объектам метод для преобразования в строковый тип - должно вернуть '_' 
7) добавить объектам метод для преобразования в численный тип - должно вернуть '<кол-во лет опыта>'
И вот такое решение:

```
var patt = /[^0-9]/g,
  period = 365,
  res = [];

function daysToYears(targetObj) {

  targetObj.forEach(function(item, idx) {
    itemExp = item.expirence.replace(patt, "")
    if (itemExp > period) {
      res = [item.name, Math.floor(itemExp / period)];
      console.log(res);
    }
  });

}

daysToYears(obj);
```

как можно переписать решение 6 и 7 пункта через классы:

Т.е в базовый класс добавляются методы приведения объекта к строке и числу, а в дочернем метод приведения к строке переопределить - должны получить "Frontender__'.

И немного не понимаю как это можно сделать в функциональном и прототипном стилях.
Я конечно понимаю,что это не фриланс,но буду очень благодарен если поможете или объясните(

Comment: 6) добавить объектам метод для преобразования в строковый тип - должно вернуть '<company>_<name>' ,а то не отобразилось

Answer (score 0):

Мы должны для каждого объекта добавить функцию, которая возвращает значение.

```js
var obj = [
  {
   name: "Test",
   expirence: "364 days",
   Frontender: true,
   Backender: false,
   company: "Company"
  },
  {
   name: "Test 2",
   expirence: "367 days",
   Frontender: true,
   Backender: false,
   company: "Company"
  },
  {
   name: "Test 3",
   expirence: "731 days",
   Frontender: true,
   Backender: false,
   company: "Company"
  }
];

obj = obj.map(o => ({ //Перебираем весь массив
  ...o,               // Добавляем в новый объект значение из старого
  getName() {         // Создаем новый метод, для п.6
                  // PS getName() тоже самое что и getName: function()
   return `${this.company}_${this.name}`;
  },
  daysToYears(){     // Создаем новый метод, для п.7
   return Math.floor(this.expirence.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") / 365);
  }
}));
                 // Проверяем
console.log(" LOG ___ ", obj[1].getName());
console.log(" LOG ___ ", obj[2].daysToYears());
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,все понятно показали)

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть в функциональном и прототипном стилях?